# How to offset a column copy with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I am trying to copy columns from one excel workbook to another, here is where I'm at rn :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('220526 MA V3.0.1 John Cpath Right Point list.xlsx')

wb2 = load_workbook('OC PATH.xlsx')


ws_1 = wb['Point List']
ws_2 = wb2 ['OC Point List']

for src, dst in zip(ws_1['B:B'], ws_2['B:B']):
    dst.value = src.value 
    
wb.save(filename = '220526 MA V3.0.1 John Cpath Right Point list.xlsx')
wb2.save(filename = 'OC PATH.xlsx')
```

It's working fine as long as I only want to copy one column, because when I try to copy column C I get a read only error because my first four rows are merged ad they need to be this way.
What I'm trying to do is having this code running from row=4 to last row instead of row 1, but I can't find a working solution.

Sorry in advance if this question is dumb, I'm just getting started in Python.
Thanks in advance to whoever will take a few minutes to help me, have a good day!

Comment: If the cells are merged then it is pointless writing data to them. If you want to do this then unmerge, copy, merge. Note, merging cells deletes all but the top-left cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the For loop part to something like this

```
for row in range (1,ws_1.max_row):
    ONE_CELL = ws_1["C" + str(row)].value # assuming you want to copy from ws_1
    ws_2["C" + str(row)].value = ONE_CELL # assuming you want to paste to row C
wb2.save("anything you like.xlsx")
```

Hopefully, if I understood your question correctly, you got your answer.

Also, don't need to save the workbook that you are coping from ;)

Comment: Hi man tanks a lot for your answer, I appreciate.
The "ONE CELL" you wrote, should be the C4 (for example) from the first sheet at first and then the C4 from the second sheet right? I'm on the phone rn so I can't try but 'm trying to make sure I understood your program.

Sorry again if these questions seem dumb I'm really trying my best :D

Comment: I think I am not able to comprehend your question, and don't call doubts "dumb".
Also, me being a beginner, I too ask some vague questions.

if you want to run it from row 4 --> change the for loop to this<br>
for row in range(4,ws_1.max_row)<br>
Also, the ONE_CELL is a variable so doesn't matter if it is C4